# LiveCode-Custom button can't show on android emulator and real mobile phone

Tags: android-emulator, livecode, custom-button

when I develop a custom button with LiveCode, I met a problem:
I just follow the lesson(https://lessons.livecode.com/m/4071/l/6852-how-to-create-a-rollover-button-with-icon-images) to make a custom button,  it can't show in the android Emulator when i test it, and also can't show on the real moblie phone when I save as a standalone application .
Is anybody knows the reason or met the similar problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you not see the button at all or do you not see the images swap? Remember that you don't have a "hover" state on the mobile and will thus not see the image swapping. It is also good if you add your LiveCode version.

Comment: Hi hliljegren，thanks for your quickly reply. The problem is solved.
The reason is : I use the icons from “Standard Icons ” Image library，then I can't see the button at all. When use the icons from "This Stack" Image library, then the button shows OK.
But I still don't know why?
My LiveCode version is V9.6.1 |Build 15522, and android studio 4.1.2

Comment: I guess that the standard icons are not copied over to the standalone then. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Just realised. Have you selected the "Copy Referenced Files" under "Copy Files" in the "Save as Standalone" dialog?

Comment: Hi hliljegren， sorry for lately reply. I selected the "Copy Referenced Files"